# com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Invalid parameter: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, twilio, twilio-api

I am working on a **SpringBoot** project, where I want to implement **Mobile Number OTP Verification** using **Twilio.** I am using the following versions-

1. Spring: 6
2. SpringBoot: 3.1.3
3. Java: 17
4. Twilio-

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
           <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
           <version>9.11.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

I referred the following docs and implemented accordingly-
https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api#user-verification-workflow
and  https://www.twilio.com/blog/phone-number-verification-java-spring-boot-verify-totp.

My code-
**Config-** I have verified all the ids and tokens

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("twilio")
public class TwilioConfig {
    private String accountSid;
    private String authToken;
    private String trialNumber;

    private String messagingServiceSid;

    public void setAccountSid(String accountSid) {
        this.accountSid = accountSid;
    }

    public void setAuthToken(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
    }

    public void setTrialNumber(String trialNumber) {
        this.trialNumber = trialNumber;
    }

    public void setMessagingServiceSid(String messagingServiceSid) {
        this.messagingServiceSid = messagingServiceSid;
    }

    public TwilioConfig(){

    }

    public String getAccountSid() {
        return accountSid;
    }

    public String getAuthToken() {
        return authToken;
    }

    public String getTrialNumber() {
        return trialNumber;
    }

    public String getMessagingServiceSid() {
        return messagingServiceSid;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TwilioConfig{" +
                "accountSid='" + accountSid + '\'' +
                ", authToken='" + authToken + '\'' +
                ", trialNumber='" + trialNumber + '\'' +
                ", messagingServiceSid='" + messagingServiceSid + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Twilio Initializer-**

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TwilioInitializer {

    Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwilioInitializer.class);

    private final TwilioConfig twilioConfig;

    @Autowired
    public TwilioInitializer(TwilioConfig twilioConfig) {
        this.twilioConfig = twilioConfig;
        logger.info("Initializing Twilio");
        Twilio.init(
                twilioConfig.getAccountSid(),
                twilioConfig.getAuthToken()
        );
        com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.Service service = com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.Service.creator("My First Verify Service").create();
        logger.info("Twilio initialized");

    }
}
```

and, **Service-**

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification;
import com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.VerificationCheck;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Service
public class SmsSenderImpl implements SmsSender {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SmsSenderImpl.class);

    private final TwilioConfig twilioConfig;

    @Autowired
    public SmsSenderImpl(TwilioConfig twilioConfig) {
        this.twilioConfig = twilioConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendSms(SmsRequest smsRequest) {
        Twilio.init(twilioConfig.getAccountSid(), twilioConfig.getAuthToken());

        String phoneNumber = "+91" + smsRequest.getPhoneNumber().trim();
        try {
            logger.info("twilioConfig: " + twilioConfig);
            logger.info("Sending otp: " + smsRequest);
            Verification verification = Verification.creator(twilioConfig.getMessagingServiceSid(), // this is your verification sid
                    phoneNumber, //this is your Twilio verified recipient phone number
                    "sms" // this is your channel type
            ).create();

            logger.info("Verification status: " + verification.getStatus());

            logger.info("OTP has been successfully generated, and awaits your verification {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void verifyOTP(String otp, String to) {
        Twilio.init(twilioConfig.getAccountSid(), twilioConfig.getAuthToken());
        logger.info("Verifying otp: " + otp);

        try {

            VerificationCheck verificationCheck = VerificationCheck.creator(twilioConfig.getMessagingServiceSid()).setTo(to.trim()).setCode(otp.trim()).create();

            logger.info("verify otp, Verification status: " + verificationCheck.getStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

**Problem-**
When I use the method- **sendSms** in service layer, I get the following error-

```
com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Invalid parameter
    at com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.VerificationCreator.create(VerificationCreator.java:184)
    at com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.VerificationCreator.create(VerificationCreator.java:32)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:40)
```

I have chosen the service-
Messaging->Services->New-Service-> Service Type- **"Verify Users"**.
[image]
I am not able to understand where is the issue. I have also created a service on Twilio and tested it on using https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/sms/try-it-out/send-an-sms. But, I am getting error in the code and I can't find the issue. Please help!

Comment: It seems to me that you are missing `EnableConfigurationProperties` on TwilioProperties due to which its instance is set of null values which of course is not acceptable by Twilio. Can you debug it and verify this behaviour ? What are the values passed to service ?

Comment: I have checked all the properties in console using Logger. No value is null and I am not getting any NullPointerException. A TwilioConfig object has been autowired in Service class. It holds all the values. Please correct me if I misunderstood something you specified. Thanks!

Comment: Then I am afraid, you need to debug into Twilio VerificationCreator source code to see why it is throwing the exception.

Comment: Can you check that the value of `twilioConfig.getMessagingServiceSid()` is "VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"?

Comment: Yes its a non-null string not starting, but not starting with V- MG97d8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX99bd82e16e745 found under- Messaging->Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a service SID that starts with `VA`.

You want to use the **"Verify (VA)"** service but you are using the `SID` for the **"Messaging (MG)"** service.

There are some more mistakes (if you don't do it on purpose);

- Your `TwilioInitializer` class is creating a service for the **Verify Service** every time you run your code. *If you do this on purpose, it's fine, but if you do it unknowingly; you don't need to create a service every time.*
- You only need to run the `Twilio.init(...);` block once, you don't need to run it in every method.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for pointing it out. I have currently chosen the "Verify Users" type messaging service which gives me a MG token. Am I using the wrong service? Should I use something else other than Messaging?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I found the "Verify services" under more products. I guess I need to use that. Thanks for helping me!